# Looping with /node in BAT file

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%i in (0,1,4) do (
SET count=1
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`wmic /node:'SERVER_NAME' cpu get loadpercentage`) DO (
SET var!count!=%%F
SET /a count=!count!+1
)
set var=%% %var2%
echo CPU Usage: %var%
)
endlocal
pause
```

Hi All. I'm running a simple loop in a BAT file and want to get the CPU % to show over 5 loops. The looking is working as intended - however - %var% is not being populated.

If I remove the do function and just have the wmic command, it produces and loops fine.

I'm missing something blazingly obvious here but can't see it. Can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

```
set var=%% !var2!
echo CPU Usage: !var!
```

`var` and `var2` are empty (I presume) at the start of the outer loop, so they're replaced by *nothing* in these two statements *before* execution.

Comment: Perfect - Thanks. So the ! holds the data in the variable? (asking so I understand rather than just have the answer)

Comment: Also - if I may ask - how to I add up each value in !var2! to I can get a total?

Comment: `!var!` when `delayedexpansion` has been invoked returns the *run-time* value of the variable (as it changes through the operation of the loop). `%var%` is the *parse-time* value - the value it had at the time that the *entire* statement was parsed - checked for validity. Given that `total` has a value of `0` before the outer `for` is reached, then `set /a total=total+var2` will sum all the values of `var2` encountered into `total`. echo !total!` will display the total of the `var2`s. After the nested `for`s have been completed, !total!==%total%.

Comment: You Sir, are awesome. Thanks for the detailed response which I understand :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not *explained* what you want to do. If you want an *average*, then you should *accumulate* the CPU % and divide the sum at end. It seems your code just show *the second value* from the 5 samples, instead of accumulate the *second line* from the 5 values.

This works for me:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set var2=0
for /l %%i in (0,1,4) do (
   SET count=1
   FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`wmic cpu get loadpercentage`) DO (
      if !count! equ 2 SET /A var2=var2+%%F
      SET /a count=!count!+1
   )
)
set /A var=var2/5
echo CPU Usage: %var%
endlocal
pause
```

The `SET /a count=!count!+1` line may be written in this simpler form: `SET /a count+=1`.

Comment: Hi @Aacini - I did say I just wanted to get %var2% populated :) I can do the math to get the average - but it wasn't populating %var% - and the reason as mentioned below, was because it was reseting the value to 0 - I'm now calling with !var! and it's working a treat:) But thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes PowerShell can be simpler:

```
(Get-Counter -ComputerName 'SERVER_NAME' '\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time' -MaxS 5 | Select -ExpandP CounterSamples | Select -ExpandP CookedValue | Measure -Average).Average
```

Even from a batch file:

```
@PowerShell -C "(Get-Counter -ComputerName 'SERVER_NAME' '\Processor(_Total)\%% Processor Time' -MaxS 5 | Select -ExpandP CounterSamples | Select -ExpandP CookedValue | Measure -Average).Average"
```

Just change `SERVER_NAME` as appropriate

Comment: Thanks @Compo I'll have a look in to this. Newbie in terms of bat files :/